# Why doesn't time for a simple update scale linearly with the number of records?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am running some performance tests and I started with a dataset of 900.000 records the update took 10 seconds or about 90000 records per second. Then I increased the number of records to 9.000.000 and the update took 170 seconds or about 52941 records updated per second.

Why does the number of records updated per seconds drop when the total number of records increases?

The distribution in the data is the same, the larger set is the smaller set copied 10 times. The size of the data and log files did indeed increase since I copied the data 10 times. I did shrink the log file after that. There is no other workload on the database server at this moment.

The stored procedure doing the update is the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updatePoints      
    @ids NVARCHAR(MAX)    
AS 
    DECLARE @points1 INT
    DECLARE @points2 INT

    SET @points1 = 1
    SET @points2 = 2

    UPDATE p
    SET points = (0 + CASE WHEN p.[x] = m.[x] AND p.[y] = m.[y]
                              THEN @points1
                              ELSE 0
                      END + 
                      CASE WHEN p.[u] = m.[u] AND p.[v] = m.[v]
                              THEN @points2
                              ELSE 0
                      END)
    FROM p 
    JOIN  m ON m.id = p.mid
    JOIN platform.Split(@ids) i ON i.Value = m.id
    WHERE m.[status] = 1
```

Comment: Does the split function scale linearly? I'd test that first. If it does please post the plan.

Comment: @ids contains the same 10 id's in both cases so the performance of the split function is equal.

Comment: I am seeing a 800% difference in estimated rows and actual rows. I will update the statistics tomorrow (don't have the proper permission currently) and see if the problem persists and update the question accordingly.

Comment: That might be because of the TVF. It will assume it contains 1 row not 10 so might propagate from there. What join types and what join order do you get and what is the estimated vs actual coming out of each iterator? Also if you insert the result from `split` into a `#temp` table with a primary key on `id` first does that improve things? (This will allow it to use statistics on the split result)

Answer (score 5):

If you post the execution plans there may be obvious differences that we can highlight. Other than plans it could be:

- Different distribution of values in the dataset, leading to more frequent page splits
- Data and or log file growth
- A sort or hash operation spilling to tempdb
- Contention with other workloads

Need more information (queries, sample data, schema, plans) for better answers.

Comment: Ok I will collect them and update the question with them. THanks so far.

Comment: Marked this answer as correct since the problem was out of date statistics which was visible in the execution plan as a difference in nr of expected and actual rows.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the execution plans? There could be several explanations. The plan might have changed. Or maybe in your first test the data was already in cache whereas in the second case it had to be read from disc.